# Two definitions of unconditional convergence in a normed vector space $X$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

I know that the followings are equivalent for a Banach space $X$:
A series $\sum f_n$ unconditionally converges if

1. $\sum f_{\sigma (n)}$ converges for every permuation $\sigma : \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$.
2. $\sum f_{n_{k}}$ converges for every subsequence $(n_k)$.

I came across with an exercise that asked to show the equivalence of these two definitions for normed vector spaces, but I cannot easily solve this, and I began to doubt that the exercise was assuming $X$ to be a Banach space. Is this true for normed vector spaces? If so, how do I prove it, and if not, what is a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completeness is needed.

Let $Y = \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, and consider the subspace $X = c_{00}$ of sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms. In $X$, consider the sequence whose terms are

$$f_n = (-1)^n 2^{-\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\cdot e_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor},$$

where $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the standard orthonormal basis sequence. It's clear that in $Y$ the series

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} f_n$$

is absolutely convergent, hence unconditionally convergent. Since

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} f_n = 0 \in X,$$

the series is also unconditionally convergent in $X$ according to definition 1.

It is also evident that

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} f_{2n}\in Y \setminus X,$$

so this subseries is not convergent in $X$. Hence definition 1 does not imply definition 2 without completeness.