# Unconditional and absolute convergence in non-Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, absolute-convergence

I know that, by Dvoretzky-Rogers theorem, we know that in a Banach space $X$ the following are equivalent:

1. $X$ is of finite dimension.
2. Every unconditonally convergent series is absolutely convergent.

But, what if $X$ is a normed but not complete space. Is the previous theorem still true, or there are examples of infinite dimensional non-Banach spaces where every unconditionally convergent series is also absolutely convergent?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: This is only hypothetical, but, if we denote by $\tilde{X}$ the completion of $X$, then maybe there could be a way, assuming that $X$ has property $2.$, to give $\tilde{X}$ that property too via some density argument, which would imply that $\tilde{X}$ is finite-dimensional thanks to the theorem you mentioned, and thus that $X$ is too? I don't know.

Comment: @BrunoB Your idea is fine. For $x_n\in \overline{X}$ there are $y_n\in X$ such that $\|x_n-y_n\|\le 2^{-n}.$ Thus unconditional.convergence of $\sum x_n$ is equivalent to that property for $\sum y_n.$ The same equivalence holds for the absolute convergence.

Comment: It seems that in the [original paper from Dvoretzky and Rogers](https://www.pnas.org/doi/abs/10.1073/pnas.36.3.192), completeness was only used for a Cauchy implies convergent argument towards the end, so that the Dvoretzky-Rogers theorem holds for all normed spaces if we replace unconditional convergence by unconditional Cauchy convergence (which is equivalent in a Banach space to unconditional convergence), see Theorem $3$ and the remark preceding it. In case this helps, or in case this is satisfying enough.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc The problem is that we'd need the sum $\sum_n y_n$ to be in $X$, which we wouldn't know just from this construction right? But I could be missing something simple.

Comment: @BrunoB You are right. The Cauchy condition should be used as there is no guarantee that $\sum y,_n$ is unconditionally convergent to the element in $X.$

Comment: @BrunoB  Do you know if the following holds: If $\sum x_n$ is unconditionally convergent then for every bounded numerical sequence $a_n$ the series $\sum a_nx_n$ is convergent ?  I have impression that I have come across this but I do not remember the source.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I found a reference in Banach spaces: Theorem $2.8$, page $23$, of [this primer](https://heil.math.gatech.edu/papers/bases.pdf), lists such a criterion, but even looking on MSE I could not find a proof of the statement for generic normed spaces. The closest I'm seeing is the French Wikipedia page for [unconditional convergence](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_inconditionnelle) seemingly stating it as fact for abelian topological groups but using the same primer I linked (albeit the expanded version) as source, which deals with Banach spaces. But maybe it's adaptable?

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks. I was interested in the Banach space case.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Note that some of the implications between the equivalent-in-Banach-spaces assertions will fail in incomplete normed spaces, see for example this post: [Two definitions of unconditional convergence in a normed vector space $X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2469394)

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc If you would be interested, I wrote up an answer based on a MathOverflow thread. I hope I didn't write nonsense, I just trusted the MO post, so feel free to tell me if I messed up if you know more on the matter (but please don't feel obligated).

Answer (score 1):

<s>This is only a partial answer since it doesn't answer the question outright but provides a quite similar statement which is true and generalises the one in Banach spaces. I didn't want to leave it as only a comment, but I am aware that this somewhat "avoids" the question.</s> This is not true anymore, it's an actual answer!

Firstly, a quick comment on what was my first approach: in their original paper (which I'll link [here](https://www.pnas.org/doi/epdf/10.1073/pnas.36.3.192)), Dvoretzky and Rogers did observe themselves that completeness of their Banach space $B$ was only used once, towards the end, hence the statement below holds, which is a consequence of their Theorem $3$ and the remark preceding it:

> Let $X$ be a normed space. The following assertions are equivalent:
>
> - $X$ is finite-dimensional;
> - Every unconditionally Cauchy convergent series is absolutely convergent.

This is a simple generalisation of the original statement since unconditional Cauchy convergence is equivalent to unconditional convergence in Banach spaces. The problem is that I do not know whether their proof method can be adjusted to prove your claim.

However, the theory of nuclear spaces seems to come to the rescue: I'll refer to [this answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/318967) by Robert Fueber, itself based on Schaefer's *Topological Vector Spaces*. **Disclaimer**: I do not know that much myself on the theory presented, so I'll be more than happy to hear (well, I guess read) other users's opinions on my answer, whether I did put the pieces of this puzzle correctly, or if I missed or misunderstood something.

I'll quote the relevant parts of the answer for self-containment:

> For $E$ a locally convex space, let $\ell^1[E]$ denote the set of absolutely summable ($\mathbb{N}$-indexed) series and $\ell^1(E)$ the set of unconditionally summable series. These spaces admit locally convex topologies such that the inclusion $\ell^1[E] \to \ell^1(E)$ is continuous. (...)
> (...) It is then true that the inclusion mapping $\ell^1[E] \to \ell^1(E)$ is a linear homeomorphism iff $E$ is a nuclear space. This is actually Pietsch's sharpened version of Grothendieck's theorem.(...)
> (...) If $E$ is infrabarrelled, for instance if $E$ is a normed space, then the mapping $\ell^1[E] \to \ell^1(E)$ is a linear homeomorphism iff it is surjective, so **these spaces are nuclear iff unconditional and absolute summability coincide**. Infinite-dimensional Banach spaces are not nuclear, so every infinite-dimensional Banach space contains an unconditionally convergent series that is not absolutely convergent. This fact was originally proven by Dvoretsky and Rogers, in quite a different way.(...)

I added the bolding to emphasize the key information: nuclear normed spaces are exactly the normed spaces where unconditional and absolute summability are one and the same, yet in Schaefer's book the definition of absolute summability already requires unconditional summability, thus this should be exactly saying that a locally convex space is nuclear iff every unconditionally convergent series is absolutely convergent, which would be exactly what we want. There only remains to see which normed spaces are nuclear.
Robert only mentions Banach spaces, but it's actually a fact that no infinite-dimensional normed space, even non-Banach, can be nuclear (see the third property [listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_space#Properties)), hence the nuclear normed spaces are exactly the finite-dimensional normed spaces, which proves your claim, and we are done.

I don't know if it's a satisfying answer, I'd be glad to see someone with more knowledge on the matter write a more confident answer, but hopefully it helped.

Comment: Thanks for such an extended answer! I'm still learning about all of this so I can't completely follow (nor tell if everything is correct) and maybe this is stupid but, with the extended answer you proved that a normed space is finite dimensional iff unconditional and absolute convergence coincide but, what I was asking is what if we only know that unconditional implies absolute convergence, but we don't know about the other direction. Maybe you've answered that, but I don't see it :/

Comment: Btw, in the case when point 2. is stated as "unconditional and absolute convergence coincide" we can infact use directly Dvoretzky-Rogers theorem, because from the direction absolute implies unconditional, in particular absolute implies convergence and then, the space is complete.

Comment: @Eparoh No no you're right! I should have seen that coming. I have a suspicion that unconditional summability probably refers to unconditional Cauchy convergence, but I haven't checked the book mentioned yet.

Comment: @Eparoh It would seem like Schaefer's definition of unconditional summability (only called summability in his book) is exactly unconditional convergence, and he also explicitly states, unlike Robert Fueber on MO, that "the completeness of $E$ can be dispensed with in Corollaries $2$ and $3$" (section $IV.10$, remark under Corollary $3$ of Theorem $10.7$) where Colloray $3$ is exactly the Dvoretzky-Rogers theorem, hence, unless I'm wrong, that would mean that this is more accurate than Robert's answer and that your claim is true, but to be frank I have no clue.

Comment: @Eparoh I think what I'll do at some point today is ask a separate question to clarify the meaning of Schaefer's remark, if that's alright with you?

Comment: I look at Schaefer's book this morning and didn't notice the remark! If the remark is true (which I suppose it is given the authors) I think you are right. Summability is defined in page 179 and in a normed space and for a sequence, I know it is equivalent to unconditional convergence of the series. What I'm not completely sure is about absolute summability because the definition there is more complex than on normed spaces, but I suppose it is exactly the same when reduced to that case and, again, absolute summability of a sequence in a normed space is equivalen to absolute convergence

Comment: Anyway, I agree that it would be better to ask a separate question about it.

Comment: @Eparoh I've just posted a question about Schaefer's remark, here's the link: [Clarification on a remark by Schaefer on nuclear spaces and absolute versus unconditional summability](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4758427)